# Préposition de / du avec le terme budget

Tags: expressions, prépositions

Est-il préférable d'utiliser la préposition "de" ou "du" dans le contexte suivant:

> Je vous fais parvenir un état de budget au courant de la matinée.

vs

> Je vous fais parvenir un état du budget au courant de la matinée.

Comment: Pouvez-vous fournir plus de contexte ?

Comment: @Random J'ai ajouté un contexte.

Comment: Le contexte consisterait ici à dire dans quel type de texte se trouve la phrase et de quel type de budget il s'agit.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais

> Je vous fais parvenir un état **du** budget **dans le** courant de la matinée.

On me dit aussi que "état du budget" ne veut pas dire grand-chose. "Extrait du budget" serait plus normal, mais le plus naturel serait de dire tout simplement:

> Je vous fais parvenir le budget dans le courant de la matinée.

Comment: Pour demander plus de contexte à la question (et effectivement c'est nécessaire) on fait un « commentaire » sous la question, on ne fait pas une « réponse ».

Comment: Oui, mais dans ce cas-ci, "état de budget" ne sonne pas tres bien de toute facon.

Comment: @Frank J'ai ajouté un contexte.

Comment: je dirais même « **l**'état du budget », non ?

Comment: On peut. "un état" sous entendrait qu'il y a plusieurs "états" car on est dans un processus de correction. Mais "l'état du budget" est parfaitement correct et je ne sens pas de grosse différence.

Comment: J'ai déjà rencontré « état de budget » dans des écrits financiers.Uun état de budget et un état du budget ne sont pas pour moi les mêmes choses. Par contre je ne suis pas comptable et préfère laisser la réponse à des experts.

Comment: Pouvez-vous expliquer quelle est la différence?